# How to extract the year from date (mm/dd/yyyy)

Tags: sed, date

How can I extract the year from a date in the form mm/dd/yyyy?

I have a text file that has the following dates:

```
01/01/2001
05/16/1970
06/08/2010
```

How can I use sed to extract only the year from each one of these dates?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `sed`, like this:

```
cat file | sed 's/[0-1][0-9]\/[0-3][0-9]\/\([12][0-9][0-9][0-9]\)/\1/g' > newfile
```

which would read your file called `file` and write the results to the new file `newfile` (replace as needed).

If you wish to collect the years you could do something like

```
cat file | sed 's/[0-1][0-9]\/[0-3][0-9]\/\([12][0-9][0-9][0-9]\)/\1/g' | tr ' ' \\n | grep . | sort -nu
```

Comment: No need to spawn `cat`, just `<file sed` or `sed 's/…' file`. Also, you can increase readability by using a different delimiter to `/`, e.g. `sed 's,…,…,g'`, then you don't need to escape literal `/`. Finally, what is the purpose of `grep`?

Comment: @Sparhawk Yes, you are right, you could use `<` but that would be less accessible in my opinion (here comes the content | here is the pipe > here goes the result). I would not be a good code golfer. The `grep .` gobbles empty lines (I do not know the file). `sed s,...` would work, although the manual says differently. It is a habit, I suppose...

Comment: Yeah, nothing is big deal really IMO. FWIW, `<file` can go at the beginning, too, i.e. `<file sed 's…' | etc`. Also `man sed` has a section at the end (`SEE ALSO`) on the "full manual", which leads to `info sed` > `sed scripts` > `The "s" Command`.

Answer (score 4):

```
echo "01/01/2001 05/16/1970 06/08/2010" > datefile
sed 's:[0-1][0-9]/[0-3][0-9]/::g' datefile
```

Result: `2001 1970 2010`

This will work both when all dates are on one line and when each date is on its own line. The separator is the `:` to assist intelligibility. The global `g` option makes all valid substitutions.

Answer (score 3):

Since the dates are in the US "MM/DD/YYYY" format, one may use GNU `date` directly on the file `dates` containing the dates:

```
$ date -f dates "+%Y"
2001
1970
2010
```

You can do fancier formatting to, like

```
$ date -f dates "+%F is in %Y and is a %A"
2001-01-01 is in 2001 and is a Monday
1970-05-16 is in 1970 and is a Saturday
2010-06-08 is in 2010 and is a Tuesday
```

The formatting sequences (`%Y` and the like) are described in the GNU `date` manual.

The input formats handled by GNU `date` are described in [the GNU coreutils manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Date-input-formats.html).

Comment: Quite lucky here that GNU `date` understands `06/08/2010` as `2010-06-08` and not `2010-08-06` [as most of the world would expect](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Date_format_by_country_%28new%29.png).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas The dates are in the US format, which GNU `date` [knows how to parse](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Calendar-date-items.html). If the dates are in another format which GNU `date` cannot parse, a simple rearrangement may be made on the input.

Answer (score 2):

For your example file, you could simply

```
cut -d / -f3 file
```

If you want to loop over those dates, pipe into a loop:

```
cut -d / -f3 file |
while read year; do ...
```

or just use `read` and split on a custom `IFS` value;

```
while IFS=/ read -r mm dd yyyy; do
    : do something with "$yyyy"
done <file
```

Comment: I never stop being baffled that people actually use this wacky date format.

Answer (score 0):

With `awk`:

```
awk -F'/' '{print $3}' textfile
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -e 's|.*/||' input_file

grep -oP '(?:^|\h)(?:\d\d?/){2}\K\d{4}(?=\h|$)' input_file
```

---

Using `grep` with `PCRE` support this can be done as shown when there are one or more date-type strings per-line in your input_file.